# How to delete content backwards until "=" at the previous line?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

I use an example of javascript code:

```
1        var a = 1;
2        var b = |{};
```

The cursor is at the position of `|`( on the character "{" when the cursor shape is block), I find out that I want `a` should be assigned an object, so I want to modify it like below:

```
1        var a = {};
```

So I want to know when cursor is on "{", how to quickly delete all the contents before "{" until the blank after the "=" sign at line 1?

In other normal editors, I'll just press backspace key to delete the code. But I don't how to achieve this in vim.

Comment: you can also press `i` and use the backspace key. No body will shoot you for that. I think.

Comment: but backspace won't delete character of above line

Comment: @AaronShen That depends on your 'backspace' setting. If it includes `eol` then backspace *will* delete line breaks. You'll also need `start` to be included in the setting. (See `:help backspace`). Don't use this method though! There are several much faster methods detailed in the answers below.

Answer (score 25):

Not sure if I totally understand the question, but if you wanted to delete until you only have  `var a = {};`, you could, from the cursor position, use <kbd>d?1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>d</kbd> takes a motion, and you can give it a search pattern with <kbd>/</kbd> for a forward search or <kbd>?</kbd> for a backward search.

Here's a small gif demonstrating this:

[image]

Comment: @Rich indeed thanks, I have updated the answer to include that.

Comment: What font is that shell using?

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown: Terminus

Answer (score 11):

If you are using vim (and not classic vi), then in your example you could do `vkd` (or `vkx`).

- `v` will put it into 'visual' (select) mode
- `k` will go up one line to put the cursor on the '1', selecting the portion you want deleted
- `d` or `x` will delete the selection

Answer (score 7):

### Delete Up

For this specific example, `dgk` is one of the quickest ways to do so.

The `d` command, as [Akshay explained](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2527/343), can be followed by a motion, deleting all the characters between where the cursor begins, and where the motion takes it to.

In your code, you want to to delete everything between the cursor position and the same column one row further up, so moving the cursor upwards with the `gk` motion (which when used with an operator is non-linewise) will achieve your goal.

**EDIT:** BobH [points out in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/how-to-delete-content-backwards-until-at-the-previous-line/2531#comment2492_2531) that this method only works when `'wrap'` is set. As such, unless you *always* have wrap set, you're probably better off using `dvk` or `vkd`, as suggested by the other answers on this page.

### Delete Words Backwards

You could also use: `d5b` or `d4B`, which will delete 5 words or 4 WORDs backwards, respectively. (`1;` is one WORD, but two regular words).

Comment: why dk will delete both current line and above line completely

Comment: @Rich if that works for you then you have a setting that enables that delete movement. I've just tested it with `vim -u NONE -U NONE` and it deletes both lines.

Comment: @Vitor You're right. Trying to figure out which setting does it, now.

Comment: Your "delete up" trick works if you replace `gk` for `k`.

Comment: @toro2k Yup! You commented as I was editing my answer to say so :).

Comment: @AaronShen Apologies for my (repeated) mistakes!

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of this trick. But I can see that you have `k` mapped to `gk`!

Comment: @Vitor Yup. Hence all the confusion you can see in my repeated edits!

Comment: BTW it turns out using `gk` as characterwise apparently requires `:set wrap` (somewhat cryptically).  I couldn't figure out why this seemingly was working for everyone else but not for me, when the help for `gk` likewise seemed to imply it should work.  The only clue was that the main meaning of `gk` had to do with wrapped lines.  Once I tried setting wrap on (kind of on a whim), voila, it worked.

Comment: @BobH You're right. Odd. That's a very poorly worded bit of help text.

Answer (score 1):

I can't yet comment, so I need to make a new answer. The keys <kbd>d</kbd>
<kbd>k</kbd> given by Rich don't work for me even when using the nocompatible option. A reason might be that the motion <kbd>k</kbd> is considered linewise by vim, in which case both lines are deleted. From `:help d`:

> An exception for the d{motion} command: If the motion is not linewise, the
>   start and end of the motion are not in the same line, and there are only
>   blanks before the start and after the end of the motion, the delete becomes
>   linewise.  This means that the delete also removes the line of blanks that you
>   might expect to remain. Use the |o_v| operator to force the motion to be
>   characterwise

It also shows the remedy: Use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to force the motion to be character-wise. This does the trick for me.

I didn't know o_v before, so here's `:help o_v`:

> v
>
> > When used after an operator, before the motion command: Force
> >                   the operator to work characterwise, also when the motion is
> >                  linewise.  If the motion was linewise, it will become
> >                 |exclusive|.
> >                If the motion already was characterwise, toggle
> >               inclusive/exclusive.  This can be used to make an exclusive
> >                    motion inclusive and an inclusive motion exclusive

Comment: The 'nocompatible' thing was a complete red herring. I messed up when I was testing because I am an idiot.

Comment: We can also use dgk, where gk is also exclusive and not linewise.